# What design pattern should be used for a workflow like this?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, workflow, microservices, soa

Let's say I have a workflow like this

```
          (1) Check for latest commit in a GitHub repo
                             |
                             |
                    (2) Is new commit?
                            / \
                        No /   \ Yes
                          /     \
                         /       \
                      End         \
                                   \
                                    \
                                  (3) Download all files
                                  /       |       \
                                 /        |        \
                     (4i) Process file i  .      Process file N
                                \         .         /
                                 \        .        /
                                  \       .       /
                                   \      .      /
                                    \     .     /
                                        End
```

and I want to have the following microservices:

- (A) Commit Checker
- (B) File Downloader
- (C) File Processer

**My question is whether each of these microservices should be a link in a sequential workflow, or whether these microservices should just contain functionalities and a separate "omniscient" microservice conducts the workflow.**

In the first case it might look like

```
A: (1),(2) ====> B:(3) ====> C:(4i),(4ii),...,(4N)
```

where each link is writing a message in a queue that gets picked up by the next link.

Because (2) is in A, that means that A is making a decision about whether to invoke B. I guess you could then say that the services are tightly coupled.

In other implementation I've suggesting, there would be a separate service X that performs the control flow and simply plugs in data to A, B, C, which would perform single tasks like

```
A: Get latest commit
B: Download all files by commit
C: Process single file
```

and then X would own/execute the logic of

- (2), i.e. deciding whether to terminate the workflow or do the next step
- Deciding to have the downloaded files processed in parallel

Which is better implementation?

Another question I have is about storage. The `Is new commit?` part means that I keep a record of commits so I can tell whether what I checked is one that I haven't checked before. **Who should keep the record of commits? Should it be considered in A's storage or a separate "workflow storage"?**

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this would be to be a `Chain of Responsibilities` where each node is responsible for checking a condition or doing a job

For example, your first phase is a logical decision:

1. "new commit?" {true|false} D
2. If true, "do stuff" stop? (visitor ?)

So, each node has the potential to execute a terminating function (which may/may not return results; the functionalist in me says it should).

From a coding perspective, it might look like this:

```
interface Responsibility<I> {
    fun apply(context:I) : Unit?
}

class GitRepo{
    val files = setOf<URI>()
    val commiters = setOf<String>()
    fun hasNewCommit() = true

}

abstract class Chained<I,N>(protected val next:Responsibility<N>) : Responsibility<I> {


}
class CheckCommited(next:Responsibility<Set<URI>>) : Chained<GitRepo,Set<URI>>(next) {
    override fun apply(gr:GitRepo) = when(gr.hasNewCommit()) {
        true -> next.apply(gr.files)
        false -> null
    }
}
class DownLoadFiles(next:Responsibility<Set<URL>>) : Chained<Set<URI>,Set<URL>>(next) {
    override fun apply(uris:Set<URI>) {
        next.apply(uris.map { downLoad(it) }.toSet())
    }
    fun downLoad(uri:URI): URL {
        return uri.toURL()
    }
}

class NotifyPeople(val people: Set<String>) : Responsibility<Set<URL>> {

    override fun apply(context: Set<URL>): Unit? {
        people.forEach {  context.forEach { sendMail(it.toString()) }}
    }

    private fun sendMail(email: String) {

    }
}

val root = CheckCommited(DownLoadFiles(NotifyPeople(setOf("joe@company.com","suzy@someplace.other"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

That aren't microservices. That's pico services and imho they are way to small to motivate all the extra maintenance and administration that a microservice require. In his excellent talk from [GOTO Conference 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgdBVIX9ifA) Martin Fowler recommends that a couple of full time developers is recommended per Microservice. If you don't have at least one that works full time with the service, then it's way to small.

To keep it simple you could use a message based architecture instead, where each internal service subscribes on messages from other internal services.

For instance when a download is complete you could send a `FileDownloaded` event from the `FileDownloader` and to which the `FileProcessor` have subscribed on. On that way there is no tight coupling between them either.

As for messaging libraries, you could for instance use my [messaging library](https://github.com/jgauffin/dotnetcqs)